# Wait for landing page on invoke-webrequest

Tags: powershell

This site returns retuns a landing page via powershell but in a browser/HttpFox will return a string of JSON

code:

```
$rep= Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $myURI -Method Post -Body "$myPOSTbody" -ContentType "application/json; charset=utf-8" -websession $SesVar -useragent $useragent
```

returns:

```
<HTML><HEAD><TITLE></TITLE></HEAD><BODY onLoad="document.AUTOSUBMIT.submit();">This page is used to hold your data while you are being authorized for your request.<BR><BR>You will be forwarded to continue the authorization process. If this does not happen automatically, please click the Continue button below.<FORM NAME="AUTOSUBMIT" METHOD="POST" ENCTYPE="application/x-www-form-urlencoded" ACTION="/public/login/wfnlogin.fcc?TYPE=aType&REALMOID=reallyLongKey"><INPUT TYPE="SUBMIT" VALUE="Continue"></FORM></BODY></HTML>
```

how can i get it to wait to return the JSON in $rep variable?

Comment: Hi, maybe try this url: `$myURI/public/login/wfnlogin.fcc?TYPE=aType&REALMOID=reallyLongKey`. This is the url where the form redirects you. Maybe you will need a bit of tweaking when merging the original URL and the `/public/...` bit, and to add a `submit` POST field with value `continue`.

Comment: i have tried all that, but to no avail.  the invoke-webrequest just won't wait for the transaction to complete like a browser